# using column value in url click event

Tags: jqgrid

I've created a grid that lists customer projects and goes to the project's page when you click the row. The problem I'm having is that the grid is passing the rowid  instead of the column value that is used in the url parameter so it's pulling up the wrong project. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "getprojects.php",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["Project ID", "Customer", "Invoice Number", "Vehicle", "Project Date"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "ProjectID", width:60},
            {name: "CustomerName", width:200},
            {name: "InvoiceNumber", width:120},
            {name: "Vehicle", width:220},
            {name: "ProjectDate", width:100}
        ],    
        onSelectRow: function (ProjectID) {
            document.location.href = "manageproject.php?pid=" + ProjectID;
        },    
        pager: "#pager",
        width: 800,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [],
        sortname: "ProjectDate",
        sortorder: "desc",
        height: 'auto',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: ""
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data returned from the server (from `getprojects.php`) should contain unique `id` property, which identify the row and which will be used by jqGrid as the value of `id` attribute of the row (`id` of `<tr>`). If `ProjectID` contains unique value then you can use `jsonReader: { id: "ProjectID" }` option to inform jqGrid to use the property as rowid. One more way: you can add `key: true` property to the definition of the column `ProjectID`.

If `ProjectID` column don't contain unique values then you can modify the code of `onSelectRow` callback to the following:

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var projectID = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "ProjectID");
    document.location.href = "manageproject.php?pid=" + encodeURIComponent(projectID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, Oleg. The ProjectID field is unique, I just wasn't setting the id to the ProjectID field.

Comment: @RaymondMeade: You are welcome! I wrote you that you should 1) add `key: true` property to `ProjectID` (in `colModel`), 2) add jqGrid option `jsonReader: { id: "ProjectID" }``. The second step isn't required after the first one, but it's still recommended.